# How to prove that $a^x$ is crescent for $a>1$ and decrescent if $0<a<1$ using logarithms?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I need to prove that $f(x) = a^x$ is crescent when $a>1$, decrescent when $0<a<1$ and constant when $a=1$.

I just know that $$a^x = e^{\log a^x} = e^{x\log a} = (e^{\log a})^x$$

but I don't think it helps, because $e^{\log a}$ can be $>1$ or $<1$ depending on the value of $a$, and I'd arrive at the same problem. Could somebody help me?

Comment: Hint: $\log$ is increasing, so $\log(f(x))$ has the same monotonicity as $f(x)$.

Comment: Note that $y=a^x\implies \log(y)=\log(a)\,x$.  If $a<1$, then $\log(a)<0$ and $\log(y)$ is decreasing.  If $a>1$, then $\log(a)>0$ and $\log(y)$ is increasing.